# How to send a single form with files and textfields in Cappuccino Objective-J

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I have found that with Cappuccino the only way to send files from user to server is using the UploadButton class from https://github.com/MCF/FileUpload

The problem is that UploadButton creates a new form for each file. I need to send two files and 5 textfields in a single POST request.

Is it possible with Cappuccino?

Answer (score 0):

You can always drop down to the DOM in cappuccino. I suggest you do that